# MYSQL count(DISTINCT an AUTO_INCREMENT column)

Tags: mysql

The following result is quite surprising.

```
MySQL [emicall_cc_man]> SELECT count(DISTINCT `id`) from call_record;
+----------------------+
| count(DISTINCT `id`) |
+----------------------+
|              2197537 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (1.32 sec)

MySQL [emicall_cc_man]> SELECT count(`id`) from call_record;
+-------------+
| count(`id`) |
+-------------+
|     2197537 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.27 sec)
```

The id column is defined as AUTO_INCREMENT, and since it is already unique why did `SELECT count(DISTINCT id)` take 5 times longer than `SELECT count(id)` ? It seems mysql (5.7) did not take that into account at all.

Is it a bug or some other explanation ?

```
CREATE TABLE `call_record` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `sid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`seid`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: If you suspect a bug raise it as such with the mysql team - or you could download the source code and figure it out yourself.https://bugs.mysql.com/ . Thing is who cares if it takes longer it takes longer..you can't optimise it anyway..if it's an issue you may need to consider an alternate approach to whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: I don't have much experience with mysql so I am more hoping someone can help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

The distinct clause  implies that the result is obtanied  using a temp table managed
by then db engine that starting from the original is used for group by the values before select the finale result..

Comment: If distinct clause uses temp table it may explain but I still feel the result it is too bad.

Comment: I think the OP is suggestng this is unnecessary given the data is defined as distinct in the first place. I kind of see his/her point but no doubt mysql team have their reasons.

Comment: If you use EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT() and EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT()) it says that it uses indexes on both of them, not a temp table

Comment: @ValeriuCiuca then how do you explain this result ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html (DISTINCT combined with ORDER BY needs a temporary table) - You don't have ORDER BY, so it shouldn't use a temporary table. Also:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @ValeriuCiuca why the result was so poor then ?

Comment: It could be that MySQL explain is lying :)

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT() it's an extra operation that consumes CPU cycles. Why would someone use COUNT(DISTINCT) on a unique column instead of COUNT?

Comment: That is another story, the code was generated by laravel